# CMake POST_BUILD custom command ignores file dependencies

Tags: cmake

I want to run a script every time my project has been built, **but also** if any of the dependency files have changed. Right now I have:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET kernel POST_BUILD
    # doesn't work :(
    DEPENDS build-iso.sh limine.cfg
    BYPRODUCTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/kernel.iso
    COMMAND ./build-iso.sh $<TARGET_FILE:kernel> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/kernel.iso ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/iso_root
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    VERBATIM
)
```

It works fine if I edit any of the source code, but if I *only* change something on `limine.cfg`, the command isn't ran on `cmake --build build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says,

> The command becomes part of the target and will only execute when the target itself is built. If the target is already built, the command will not execute.

<sup>See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events</sup>

So it does not matter that `limine.cfg` was modified because `kernel` *wasn't built*.

---

`POST_BUILD` plus `BYPRODUCTS` is usually a sign that you want `OUTPUT` with a dependency on that target, plus a custom target to drive the `OUTPUT` command. Something like this:

```
set(kernel_iso "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/kernel.iso")
set(iso_root "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/iso_root")
set(build_script "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build-iso.sh")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${kernel_iso}"
    COMMAND "${build_script}" "$<TARGET_FILE:kernel>" "${kernel_iso}" "${iso_root}"
    DEPENDS
      "${build_script}"
      limine.cfg
      kernel  # File-level dependency on `kernel`.
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    VERBATIM
)

add_custom_target(kernel_iso ALL DEPENDS "${kernel_iso}")
```

Note that the `$<TARGET_FILE:kernel>` generator expression implicitly adds a *target-level* dependency on `kernel`, but not a *file-level* dependency. This would mean that building `kernel_iso` would not bring `kernel` up to date. By naming `kernel` in `DEPENDS`, we establish the necessary file-level dependency.